# mysql combining data from multiple identical tables in a view

Tags: mysql

i have 13 different locations (currently) and each location has their own mysql database and set of tables for it's customers, etc.  the tables in each location are identical in structure and name (but of course the data differs for each location).

for simplicity, consider one of my tables that contains all of the customers for that location (table = customers).  i have created a view (view = uber_customers) that UNION's all of these tables and added a new column in the view that shows which location the customer is from (in case there are dupes).  so whenever a new customer is added to a location, they are dynamically available in the uber_customers view.  so all that works great.  (it should be noted that it's slow to search a view like this... since you can't index a view... but it's fast enough for my application).

my challenge is that i add a few new locations each year.  when i add a location, i have to go into each of my views (there is one per each of the dozen tables) and update each view to include the new location.  i have a list of locations in a table.

is there a method by which i could dynamically update my uber_customer view to include more tables as i add locations to the locations table?

thinking of a procedure perhaps?  or is there a better approach?

Comment: Updating one or a handful of views when you add a new customer database does not seem like an onerous task.

Comment: You could write a Store procedure that examine master DB, and for each table combined with you location table, dynamicaly create the ALTER VIEW command for each view. It's not easy but it can be done.